# Trying to connect to local SQLServer, Run time error 91

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I'm trying to simply connect to my local SQL Server 2014, but I keep getting the runtime error 91

> Object variable or with block variable not set

I've added reference ActiveX Data Objects Library 2.8, and according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131321.aspx the SQL Server Native client is installed with the SQL Server as default.

What can be the issue?

EDIT: How silly, the error comes from forgetting to initialize the class object.

Code

```
Private Sub ConnectSQL()

    Dim ADODBConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ADORecordset As ADODB.Recordset

    ADODBConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;" _
         & "Server=(local);" _
         & "Database=Sample1;" _
         & "Integrated Security=SSPI;" _
         & "DataTypeCompatibility=80;"

    ADODBConnection.Open

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this the **Express** edition of SQL Server 2014 by any chance? The Express edition is - by default, unless you specifically change it - installed as a **named instance** with an instance name of `SQLEXPRESS`, and therefore you need to use `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` as server/instance name for the `server=.....` value. Also: SQL Server 2014 doesn't support the compatibility level 80 (SQL Server 2000) anymore.

Comment: SQl Server 2014 Standard edition. Ohh, what would be a correct connectionstring? I'm getting quite confused about all different connectionstrings out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'new ' keyword as bellow and try

```
 Dim ADODBConnection As new ADODB.Connection 
 Dim ADORecordset As new ADODB.Recordset
```